# How to change button text and disable button on click event in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

How do you change the text of a <button> when that button is clicked in angular2?

For example, changing the button text from "Save" to "Saving..." and then also set it to be disabled.

I know how to do this in AngularJS, jQuery, and plain JS, and I have some ideas on how to do this in Angular2, but I wanted to make sure I'm not doing it in some outdated or convoluted way when it comes to Angular2.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
<button (click)="setSaving($event.target, 'saving')">save</button>
```

and then in your component:

```
setSaving(element, text){
  element.textContent = text;
  element.disabled = true;
}
```

You can also set the properties using the `Renderer`

Comment: thanks, cleaner than my ideas.  One thing, you had element.attributes.disabled = true, which didn't seem to work for me, however, element.disabled = true did work.  I've edited your post to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example for asynchronous calls that worked for me:

Template:

```
<button (click)="loadMore($event.target)">load more</button>
```

Component (pseudocode):

```
export class MyComponent{

    button;

    constructor(private _apiService: ApiService){}

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.load();
    }

    load()
    {
        this._apiService
            .getAsyncFrom( '/sample/url' )
            .subscribe(data=> {

                // do something with your data

                // enable it
                if(this.button)
                {
                    this.button.textContent = 'load more';
                    this.button.disabled=false;
                }
            });
    }

    loadMore(element)
    {    
        // assign to class
        this.button = element;

        //disable it
        this.button.textContent = 'loading...';
        this.button.disabled=true;

        this.load();
    }
}
```

Basically assign the element to the class and access it where you need it.