# how can I change the text inside the button when I make hover on it in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, frontend

[image: enter code here]

[image]

I need to change the text inside the button when I make hover on it like these photos,
I already did the active but, I need only change the text.

```
<button
   type="submit"class="btn"
   *ngFor="let available of availableTime; let i = index"
   >
    {{ available.value}} 
</button>
```

Comment: have you already tried looking at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41489355/how-to-change-button-text-and-disable-button-on-click-event-in-angular2

Comment: yes I tried this.

Answer (score 0):

An idea might be to use `mouseover` and `mouseout` events on the button element.
In the HTML template you should do something like:

```html
<button (mouseover)="changeButtonText()" (mouseout)="resetButtonText()">
  {{ buttonText }}
</button>
```

and in the typescript component:

```js
[...]
export class ExampleComponent {
  buttonText: string = 'Initial text';

  changeButtonText() {
    this.buttonText = 'New text - Hover';
  }

  resetButtonText() {
    this.buttonText = 'Initial text';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a CSS class for the hover state of the button

```
.hover-text {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Then, inside component, define a variable to store the text for the hover state:

```
hoverText = "Book Now";
```

now using ngClass directive to apply the CSS class to the button when it is hovered and change the text to the defined variable

```
<button
   type="submit"class="btn"
   *ngFor="let available of availableTime; let i = index"
   [ngClass]="{'hover-text': isHovered}"
   (mouseover)="isHovered = true"
   (mouseout)="isHovered = false"
   >
    {{ isHovered ? hoverText : available.value}} 
</button>
```

when the mouse is hovered over the button the "hover-text" class will be applied and the text inside the button will change to the value of the "hoverText" variable

Comment: thank you but I need the hover when the button is active only the mouseover work in all the buttons in the same time  when I hover on a button